# Retrieve number of rows updated

Tags: oracle, rows, dynamic-sql, rowcount

Below Dynamic SQL is updating 1319 rows.

`l_sql := 'UPDATE '||l_prefix||'CRS_CUSTOMERS SET CUSTOMER_SOURCE_REF_ID = :REF_ID EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql USING i.CUSTOMER_REF_ID, i.CUSTOMER_ID;`

`TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT);` The rowcount output is just one? How can i use any script to retrieve actual number of rows affected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
l_sql := 'UPDATE '||l_prefix||'CRS_CUSTOMERS SET CUSTOMER_SOURCE_REF_ID = :REF_ID';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql USING i.CUSTOMER_REF_ID, i.CUSTOMER_ID;
dbms_output.put_line('Updated ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows');
```

However, it will not work because you specified only one bind variable (`:REF_ID`) but you provided two values (`i.CUSTOMER_REF_ID` and `i.CUSTOMER_ID`). Bind variables and values have to match.

If `SQL%ROWCOUNT` returns "1" then you updated one row - check your UPDATE statement if you are not happy with that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_sql varchar2(200);
  3    l_cnt number;
  4  begin
  5    l_sql := 'update emp set comm = 100 where deptno = 20';
  6    execute immediate 'begin ' || l_sql ||'; :x := sql%rowcount; end;' using out l_cnt;
  7    dbms_output.put_line('Updated ' || l_cnt || ' rows');
  8  end;
  9  /
Updated 5 rows

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: `l_sql := 'UPDATE '||l_prefix||'CRS_CUSTOMERS SET CUSTOMER_SOURCE_REF_ID = '||i.CUSTOMER_REF_ID ||' WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = '||i.CUSTOMER_ID ||';`
 `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'begin ' || l_sql ||'; :x := sql%rowcount; end;' using out p_TotalUpdatedCRS;`

Comment: i have other bind variables in `l_sql,` how can achieve together with the count?